# How to change Nightwatch test suite name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

Is it possible to change a test suite name in Nightwatch.js?

I checked the documentation and it seems that a test suite name is generated automatically from JS file name, but I want to pass this name as a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

In **Nightwatch**, a *test suite* (or simply *test*) is just a JS file that contains *test cases* (*steps*). So if you want to change the name of your test suite, you just have to rename your file.

Moreover, Nightwatch is based on **Node.js**, which means that you can access command line arguments using `process.argv` in your automation script. For example, if you run `nightwatch -t tests/script.js`, `process.argv` looks like this:

```
[
  '/usr/local/bin/node',
  '/usr/local/bin/nightwatch',
  '-t',
  'tests/script.js'
]
```

You can then run `nightwatch -t tests/script.js Foo` and get `Foo` thanks to `process.argv[4]` in your Nightwatch script.

Comment: this is correct i access command arguments via process.args but unfortunately i can't change test suite name as you described.

Comment: Do you want to change the name of the test suite or the name of a test case? For the test suite, you just have to rename your file. If you want to do this dynamically, the easiest solution would be to create a simple Bash script that renames your file and runs Nightwatch tests. The given name from CLI would be `$1` in your shell script.

Comment: i implement a workaround solution as you mentioned. i create a power shell script and change file name before run nightwatch script for changing test suite name.thank you for your help.

Comment: If you think your issue is solved, please accept the answer to "close" this question. Have a nice day! ;)